# Optimizing memory for Nimbus network album

Tags: ios, afnetworking, image-caching, nimbus-ios

I have an application which uses a view controller which extends `NetworkPhotoAlbumViewController`, which in turn extends `NIToolbarPhotoViewController`

Basically it implements all the NI protocols, such as  `NIPhotoAlbumScrollViewDataSource`,   `NIPhotoScrubberViewDataSource`, `NIOperationDelegate`, `NIPhotoAlbumScrollViewDelegate` and the only customization are `didReceiveMemoryWarning`:

```
- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    NSLog(@"Nimbus Photo Album memory warning");
    [self.highQualityImageCache reduceMemoryUsage];
    [self.thumbnailImageCache reduceMemoryUsage];
    NSLog(@"Nimbus Photo Album end 0memory warning");
}
```

and `addOperation` to reduce number of concurrent downloads:

```
-(void) addOperation: (AFImageRequestOperation *) operation {
    NSLog(@"operation queue size is %d", _queue.operationCount);

    BOOL found = NO;
    for (AFImageRequestOperation *op in _queue.operations) {
        if(!operation.isCancelled && [[operation.request.URL absoluteString] compare:[op.request.URL absoluteString]] == NSOrderedSame) {
            NSLog(@"found the same operation");
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found) return;

    NSInteger cancelledCount = 0;
    if (_queue.operationCount > 5) {
        for (NSOperation *operation in _queue.operations) {
            if (operation.isCancelled) {
                cancelledCount ++;
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"cancelled operation count is %d", cancelledCount);
    NSInteger count = _queue.operationCount;
    if(count - cancelledCount > 5) {
        for (NSOperation *operation in _queue.operations) {
            if(!operation.isCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"cancel operation");
                [operation cancel];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"operation is added into queue");
    [_queue addOperation:operation];
}
```

The application also uses AVFoundation for capturing photos, which are sent full res to server (and loaded later in the network album).

The problem is that if I use `NetworkPhotoAlbumViewController` and then switch to photo capture, quite often the application crashes because of lack of memory (app memory can reach something between 20 and 30 MB), even if `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and `reduceMemoryUsage` are called.

Is it possible that I am doing something wrong and the memory is not cleared correctly? Is the problem caused by `AFNetworking`? And what alternatives are to downloading some images from the web and displaying them in a photo album with thumbnail loading and panning and zooming?